# Screen blinking while screencasting | ArchLinux and Manjaro

Tags: linux, archlinux, screen-recording, manjaro, screensharing

When you try share screen or use screen recorder in Arch Linux or Manjaro, the screen is blinking like in here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvi4F.jpg

How to solve?

Answer (score 5):

If you use x11, then to solve this problem :

- Uninstall package: `xf86-video-intel`
- Remove file (if it exists): `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`
- Reboot your system

Try your screencast again...

Comment: This is not just helpful for screencasting but solved also my issue I had with screensharing on zoom. I had a massive flickering when I was sharing any application. But just as remark, this is only valid for X11. This issue doesn't occur with Wayland. Unfortunately, zoom doesn't provide application sharing on Wayland. At least for now, at least for me...

Comment: INterestingly, this solved my problem for screen sharing using applications and web applications. What might be the cause of the issue here?